# QGIS .shp joined to xlsx.vrt; Classify works, Rule-based does not

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, rule-based

Very simple set up. Tiger .shp file as a layer. Has a join to an xlsx non geo attribute table as a .vrt

.shp has join on MTFCC to MTFCC in xlsx.vrt. xlsx.vrt, has a string field with a brief label for MTFCC codes.

I go to classify on the joined label field and it works. However when I switch to Rule-based (where it copies what you did in classify) it doesn't. Asking for a count shows 0 hits for each rule.

Another odd behavior, perhaps a clue to above, when in classify, in the .shp layer, and I classify based on the label in xlsx.vrt, it creates classifications for every row in xlsx.vrt (many of which are not needed from the .shp file). This results in may sub listings under the .shp layer that actually have no data.

Ideas?